# Solution to access indexed database using Dexie from a server initialized in electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, electron, dexie

We are building a desktop application using electron and react.

We need to store the content for application in the indexed database in the electron application. The content is stored as if it's a client application similar to a web page.

Our design contains a server which allows connections from other applications installed in different IP addresses. The clients connected to the server sends data to the server and stores the data in its local indexed storage. This stored data should be allowed for access by all the clients connected.

Comment: I used Dexie library along with the request library to start server in the HTML code itself. It would not work in browser. But works perfectly in the electron environment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Dexie / indexedDB in order to gain offline support. In that case, use a sync solution. You could either build one yourself using Dexie [C](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.hook('creating')) [R](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.hook('reading')) [U](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.hook('updating')) [D](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.hook('deleting')) hooks, or you could use a complete sync solution with [sync-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-server).

Comment: Thanks for a lead David. I will check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want to run the server in the electron instance itself. Is it possible to instantiate a server along-side the electron process?

Comment: As electron is a node process you should be able to run sync-server there in the same process I assume. But I'm not an expert on electron.